# Taking a look at

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1- ***Taking a look at the brain***, ***the pons*** is part of a
>   brainstem and its nestled between the midbrain and medulla oblongata.
>   (Source: A video-lesson from youtube) (Original one)
>
> 2- ***Taking a look at the brain***, ***we*** can see that the pons is
>   part of a brainstem and its nestled between the midbrain and medulla
>   oblongata. (In my opinion, this is the right one.)

I find the second reduced phrase fine but the first reduced phrase seems awkward to me. As far as I know we should use same subjects in the both side of a sentence when using reduced phrases. I think the second is okay because the object doing the action of "taking a look at" is "we". But in the first sentence "the pons" is not the subject of the action of "taking..." I suppose.

Comment: You can't judge online lessons by the finer points of grammar. Both sentences make their meaning perfectly clear. Pupils following the lesson would understand no less from the first sentence than the second even though the first sentence just implies what the second spells out.

Comment: I understand your discomfort.  It's the same as what bugs me when people say, for example, “As a fan of Tolkien's books, the movies make some disturbing changes.”